# AWS Codepipeline selfmutate step resets StackProps env

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I am passing AWS username in env to Stackprops like this

```
interface MyInterface extends StackProps {
   user: string;
}

export class PipelineStack extends cdk.Stack {
   constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StackProps & { env: MyInterface}){
   ...

   const pipeline = new pipelines.CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
     pipelineName: 'mypipeline' + ${env.user}
   }

   ...
   
  }
}
```

When I run `cdk deploy` the pipeline correctly picks up the `user` env variable. However, after the pipeline runs `selfMutate` stage, `user` variable cannot be found.
Is there a way to persist variables passed to StackProps after the `selfMutate` stage?
I would like to keep `selfMutate` on. I am picking up the `user` value from `process.env.USER`. I understand that when I run `cdk deploy` I have a user configured and hence it picks up the user and when the pipeline selfmutates and builds again, it doesn't have an AWS user. I wanted to know if I can achieve this in some way?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I am retrieving the user name like this now:

```
user = process.env.user || process.env.AWS_USER || "";
```

Then in the build step I am passing `AWS_USER` as an environment variable with value of `env.user`